# AngularJS displays only elements that meet a certain condition

Tags: angularjs

in my `ng-repeat` list I am displaying object elements from an object array `$scope.toBuy`:

```
$scope.toBuy=[
             cookies={
                name:'cookies',quantity:0,bought:false
            },
            water={
                name:'water',quantity:0,bought:false
            },
            bananas={
                name:'bananas',quantity:0,bought:false
            },
            milk={
                name:'milk',quantity:0,bought:false
            },
            coconut={
                name:'coconut',quantity:0,bought:false
            }
        ];
```

and I initialize all element's `bought` field to `false`. How do I display in a `ng-repeat` list that only shows elements that have `false` value in their `bought` field? I tried this:

```
<ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in toBuy |  filter:{item.bought===false }">Buy 10 {{item.quantity}} {{item.name}} <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="btnOnClick(item.name)"> Bought</button></li>

     </ul>
```

but none of the elements displayed when the page is loaded. If I removed the filter, the whole list displays, which means I applied the filter wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid javascript object syntax `{item.bought===false }`

Change to

```
ng-repeat="item in toBuy |  filter:{bought:false }"
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8d26diTPsTlnYKv6ouG8?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSON` is not a **`valid JSON`**.

[image]

Try this **`valid JSON`** :

```
[{
    "name": "cookies",
    "quantity": 0,
    "bought": true
}, {
    "name": "water",
    "quantity": 0,
    "bought": true
}, {
    "name": "bananas",
    "quantity": 0,
    "bought": true
}, {
    "name": "milk",
    "quantity": 0,
    "bought": false
}, {
    "name": "coconut",
    "quantity": 0,
    "bought": false
}]
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.toBuy=[{
     "name": "cookies",
     "quantity": 0,
     "bought": true
    }, {
     "name": "water",
     "quantity": 0,
     "bought": true
    }, {
     "name": "bananas",
     "quantity": 0,
     "bought": true
    }, {
     "name": "milk",
     "quantity": 0,
     "bought": false
    }, {
     "name": "coconut",
     "quantity": 0,
     "bought": false
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in toBuy |  filter : {bought:false}">Buy 10 {{item.quantity}} {{item.name}} <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="btnOnClick(item.name)"> Bought</button></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that you can define object fields with or without "" around them. (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp). By the way what tool do you use to detect JSON invalidations?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if (or ng-show):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in toBuy">
   <div ng-if="item.bought===false">
      Buy 10 {{item.quantity}} {{item.name}} 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know this approach. however, is it possible to fix the filter instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in toBuy |  filter:item.bought==false">
```

Or

```
<li ng-repeat="item in toBuy |  filter:{bought:false}">
```

Will work, the second is a better way to achieve this.